# can't set ALTREP truelength in mutate function by dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am getting this error when I try to mutate a column and change its data type

```
Error in .shallow(x, cols = cols, retain.key = TRUE) : 
  can't set ALTREP truelength
```

The code is sourcing multiple scripts thats why I am not able to share reproducible code but the last line on code below where I am using mutate to change column data type to character is producing that error  **can't set ALTREP truelength**..see how the *dplyr* code looks like:

```
df = mutate(diag.data, value = as.character(all.disc.diag)) %>%  
  cSplit(., splitCols='value', sep = ';', direction = 'long') %>%
  subset(., !is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(., value = as.character(value))
```

Anyone who has experienced this can kindly help how they went around it with *dplyr*